# command run in docker-tramp running on the host rather than remote

Tags: org-mode, tramp, preview-latex, docker

The setup:

I have a docker container connected with a mounted volume containing an org file. The docker container has both texlive and emacs (configured exactly the way it is on my host) installed. I can open the org file and run `org-latex-preview` on the math components without any problems.

The problem:

I recently installed [docker-tramp](https://github.com/emacs-pe/docker-tramp.el) and figured I wouldn't need a separate installation of emacs in my docker containers. However, when I opened the same org file and ran `org-latex-preview` I got the following message in the `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*` buffer:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `/tmp/orgtextfP6YZ.tex'.
<*> /tmp/orgtextfP6YZ.tex
                         
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> /tmp/orgtextfP6YZ.tex
                         
No pages of output.
Transcript written on /tmp//texput.log
```

Now the `orgtextfP6YZ.tex` file is not in the docker container's `/tmp` folder; however, it has been generated in the *host's* `/tmp` folder. So the command that `org-latex-preview` uses (`dvipng`) accesses the host's `/tmp` folder, which means that `dvipng` was run on the host rather than the remote (docker container).

When I'm using a buffer I accessed through docker-tramp, any command I call using `M-!` runs in the remote. So how do I configure it (or TRAMP in general) so that commands used indirectly (called by a function in emacs) are also run in the remote?

Comment: I don't know the answer but it's probably worth opening an issue on the docker-tramp github.

Comment: I've edited the question as things became clearer to me. It seems more like a TRAMP issue than a docker-tramp issue, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the function `org--latex-preview-region`. There's the comment

```
;; Emacs cannot overlay images from remote hosts.  Create it in
;; `temporary-file-directory' instead.
```

Running on a remote host is disabled by intention.

OTOH, everything you start with `M-!` (or `M-&`) is given to a shell, which can run also remotely.

Comment: Well, I was definitely looking under the wrong hood - the problem lies with org and not tramp. Is there any way around this? I found a [patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-11/msg00583.html) that was apparently rejected.

Comment: No idea. I don't use org.